# Login page to my Google Apps domain redirects to standard Gmail login

Tags: gmail, google-workspace

I can't log in to my Google Apps email from one of the computers as it keeps redirecting me to the general Gmail login screen.

The normal Google Apps sign in page is here:

```
http://mail.google.com/a/example.com
```

But it takes me to here instead:

> https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?continue=http%3A%2F%2Fmail.google.com%2Fa%2Fexample.com%2F&service=mail&ltmpl=default&passive=true&authuser=0

I tried logging in with my email username and password and also tried email/password combination to no avail. I am able to access the mail from my home computer, due to a still active cookie, I think.

I am the admin of the domain and it is my personal homepage domain.

Comment: Have you tried the *Can't access your account?* link below the sign-in box?

Comment: I don't want to reset my password.

Comment: Then change it to what you think it already is!

Comment: Just FYI, I tried to do the same thing for my google apps domain and it works just fine.

Comment: Try clearing out your cookies/cache and other temporary files, then you try to login.

Answer (score 3):

Your domain may have been upgraded. If so, you should still be able to login from http://mail.google.com. Just enter your full email address (not just your username) when you try to sign in.

As an admin, you should also be able to login to your cpanel at http://www.google.com/a/example.com and acces your mail from there; while visiting your cpanel, you can confirm whether your domain has upgraded and force the migration if necessary.

Answer (score 3):

My solution Open IE (all previous Google logins were via Chrome). Then use the https://www.google.com/a/example.com route in. This worked in IE which had no Google account cookies etc... while the same URL via Chrome still went to the Google account (rather than Google Apps control panel)

Answer (score 0):

Try using https://www.google.com/a/example.com or from your Gmail account if you are the admin of the Google Apps you could find a link on the top right side labeled: 'Manage this domain'.

Answer (score 0):

Its a horrible bug, you can either delete your cookies or login using a different browser - example if its a problem with chrome use firefox