# Google Apps for your domain (Free Edition) login page gets redirected to gmail

Tags: gmail, google-workspace

I have already seen identical questions - [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/19568/60450) and [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/34071/60450).

I've tried all the solutions posted, checking the redirect URL in the Admin console, and deleting all cookies. However, I keep getting redirected to the Gmail login page.

I've even tried the long form of the URL (https://www.google.com/a/example.com) but that also doesn't seem to work.

Could this be because we have the FREE version? It used to work earlier though.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where do you get when browsing to https://www.google.com/a/example.com ? The GMail login page?

Comment: @VidarS.Ramdal - it goes to the gmail login page

Answer (score 1):

I have a free google apps account also and the url https://www.google.com/a/example.com redirects me to https://accounts.google.com/AccountChooser for sign in.

And after login with my admin account I get to admin panel.